# mail() function doesn't work inside laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I was testing out my mail configuration. First I did a normal mail() call in a separate .php file. That worked fine. Then I copied the exact same code inside a route callback in Laravel 4 and now it doesn't work. How is that possible?

This is the code that works:

```
$from_add = "name@your-web-site.com"; 

$to_add = "someone@gmail.com"; //<-- put your yahoo/gmail email address here

$subject = "Test Subject";
$message = "Test Message";

$headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";


mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

The adresses don't matter because I am testing with [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/)

Comment: http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/sending-e-mail-with-laravel-4-using-mail/ might help. Laravel has its own way to send email (by calling the built-in `mail` function or not). Don't miss at the beginning of the tutorial they say to edit `app/config/mail.php` stuff too.

Comment: @JScoobyCed I also tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there anything in the error log (you might have to set it up if not running as CLI)

Answer (score 1):

When working with Laravel 4, it's always advisable to use the built-in [Mail function](http://laravel.com/docs/mail).

This has a couple of advantages I wouldn't want to miss:

- You can easily test mail features by setting the pretend option to true
- It will allow you to send HTML mails using Blade views
- You can choose which way your mails should be sent depending on your server config (sendmail, phpMailer)
- You can queue mails so they will be sent later when there's less server load
- You can do stuff after mail delivery in a callback function

If you still insist on using the php `mail()` function, set your driver in `app/config/mail.php` to "mail".

Comment: I would like to but it doesn't work ... even the normal mail() function doesn't work in my route.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Email Function in Laravel](http://dixitpatel.com/form-in-laravel-with-email-function/)